# Save From Gridview using a WCF

Tags: c#, gridview, ado.net

so I am using Gridview with a WCF. I have managed to insert from textboxes to gridiview but now I am struggling to save the gridview via the WCF service. I have giving it an attempt and getting this error:

> "The parametrized query '(@Item1 narchar(4),@Item2 nvarchar(4000))
>   insert into ' expects the parameter '@item2', which was not supplied."

here is my code:

```
public string InsertProcesses(ProcessDetails proDetails)
{
    string Message;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCFTest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into SaveProcesses(Item1, Item2)values(@Item1, @Item2)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item1", proDetails.Item1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item2", proDetails.Item2);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result == 1)
    {
        Message = proDetails.Item1+ "Details accepted";
    }
    else
    {
        Message = proDetails.Item1+ "Details not accepted";
    }

    con.Close();

    return Message;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ServiceReference6.ProcessDetails det2 = new ServiceReference6.ProcessDetails();

    det2.Processes = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Item1"].Value.ToString();
    det2.Processes = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Item2"].Value.ToString();
    obj6.InsertProcesses(det2);
```

Thanks for any help that can be given. Please note this is my first time attempting a WCF.

**ProcessDetail code**

```
[DataContract] 
public class ProcessDetails 
{ 
    int id; 
    string item1; 
    string item2; 

    [DataMember] 
    public int Id 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return id; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            id = value; 
        } 
    } 

    [DataMember] 
    public string Item1 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return item1; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            item1 = value; 
        } 
    } 

    [DataMember] 
    public string Item2 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return item2; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            item2 = value; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `proDetails.Item2` null?

Comment: Item 2 has information going into it. And in the database none of them are set as a null, sorry i am new to WCF and getting confused

Comment: You have a SQL error, not a WCF error.  What you expect to be happening with Item2 is not happening.  What is `det2.Processes`?  whatever it is, you're overwriting it in your for loop when you assign the "item2" cell to it.  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Should it be `det2.Processes.Item1 = " and `det2.Processes.Item2 = " respectively?  Or something similar?  The code for `ProcessDetails` specifically would help us troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: [DataContract]
    public class ProcessDetails
    {
        int id;
        string item1;
        string item2;

        [DataMember]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Item1
        {
            get { return item1 ; }
            set { item1 = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Item2
        {
            get { return item2 ; }
            set { item2 = value; }
        }

Comment: It's better to edit your question to add code then to put it in the comments, as the comments doesn't support formatting.  I've added your code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is a SQL error - it's not related to WCF except that it happens in a WCF operation contract (method).

Based on the code for `ProcessDetails`, both `Item1` and `Item2` are not getting set in your `for` loop (you're setting the same [non-existent] property in both lines).  Something like this would seem to be more appropriate:

```
det2.Item1 = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["item1"].Value.ToString();
det2.Item2 = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["item2"].Value.ToString();
```

Also, you can use automatic properties in your Data Contract to have less code:

```
[DataContract] 
public class ProcessDetails 
{ 

    [DataMember] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public string Item1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

There's nothing wrong with the way you wrote the class, the above way just lets you do the same thing with less typing.

Comment: So its something to do with my sql database?

Comment: No - or at least not necessarily.  The issue is that your code as posted was not populating the properties `Item1` and `Item2` - you were assigning both cells from the grid to some property named `Processes` (which doesn't even exist in your DataContract code), so you were passing in null values into the parameters for your SQL command.

Comment: Processes was meant to be Item1 and Item2, i was changing the column names.. I noticed i made a short mistake which was i listed item1 twice instead of item1 and item2 where "processes" is, changed it around and i get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Thanks for the help so far by the way

Comment: the last error has cleared. when i try to save it now, this error appears "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: What line of code is that error happening on?  The error itself is pretty self-explanatory, but it could be happening in any number of places in your posted code.  Step through your code in the debugger and that should highlight the line this exception occurs on.

Comment: The error comes here:

catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

Comment: Ive located the error and sorted it out! thank you for your help buddy

Comment: You're welcome - glad you resolved it.  I've been in meetings the last couple of hours (wasn't intentionally ignoring you).